# Movie Player in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller, movieplayer

I'm doing simple movie player in swift. I have player in ViewController like this.

[image]

and i want it like this.

[image]

Here's code

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")

moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: -100, width: 600, height: 400)

moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()

self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

moviePlayer.fullscreen = true

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

}

}
```

Comment: your specific issue?

Comment: You are the one positioning the view (`moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: -100, width: 600, height: 400)`). Are you saying you don't like what you're doing? Then don't do that.

Comment: I want to automatically open movie player like on picture 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in continuation to Dharmesh reply, please update

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```

it will then be adjusted as per device screen size.

Hope it helps!

Comment: in portrait it works perfectly but in widescreen its not working, I see only half screen of player.

Answer (score 1):

Try this because it's work for me:

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568)
```

Comment: thanks u helped me but it doesnt work for widescreen :P I want to have filled

Comment: adjust the size.because above width and high will work only on iPhone 5.. :)